# Swift. Flip animation. FromView is not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, animation, view, flip

I've wrote this code to create a simple flip animation:

```
  func frontView (view:UIView) ->UIView {
        var frontView: UIView
        frontView = UIView()
        frontView.frame = view.frame

        frontView.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)


        return frontView
    }

    func backView (view:UIView) ->UIView {

        var backView: UIView
        backView = UIView()
        backView.frame = view.frame

        backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        backView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2, y: 0)

        view.addSubview(backView)

        return backView
    }

func flipViewAnimation (viewToAnimate: UIView) {

    var animationOption = self.animationOption
    var duration = self.duration



    UIView.transitionFromView(backView(viewToAnimate), toView: frontView(viewToAnimate), duration: duration, options: animationOption, completion: nil)

    //


}
```

As a viewToAnimate I use views with labels and imageViews inside, which I've created in AutoLayout. The result I'm trying to achieve more or less should look like this. First I see views filled with color, then they flip and show the content inside (labels and ImageViews).

But it works in a different way. Views appear already with content (labels and ImageViews) then just flip and again show the same content.

Answer (score 0):

I've created each view programmatically and it works very well for me now.